# Intro to C / Variables aren't printing properly

Tags: c

This code is supposed to take inputs from the user on details for a home loan and calculate how much they would pay over the life of the loan. My code takes all the inputs properly but won't print them accordingly in my "for" loop. My "Month" variable is set incredibly high and the rest of them are set to 0. How can I make my code work properly

I expected to take all the inputs for the loan balance, apr, how much is to be paid each month, and the number of years. It would then calculate the amount of money that was paid to the total balance and the amount paid to interest and print them out for each month until the the final month, where the amount paid altogether and the current balance will be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int years, month, final_month, annual_interest_rate;
    
    double loan_balance, interest_for_this_month, monthly_payment, total_interest, leftover_payment, monthly_interest_rate;
    
    printf("\n\nLoan Amount = ");
    scanf("%lf", &loan_balance);
    printf("%.2lf\n", loan_balance);
    
    printf("\n\nNumber of Years = ");
    scanf("%i", &years);
    printf("%i\n", years);
    
    printf("\n\nAnnual Interest Rate Percent = ");
    scanf("%i", &annual_interest_rate);
    printf("%i\n", annual_interest_rate);
    
    printf("\nMonthly Payment = ");
    scanf("%.2lf", &monthly_payment);
    printf("%.2lf\n", monthly_payment);
    
    monthly_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate/1200;
    
    final_month = years*12;
    //total_interest = 0; 
    
    for(month = 1; month <= final_month; month = month+1)
    { 
        interest_for_this_month = (monthly_interest_rate * loan_balance);
        total_interest = (total_interest + interest_for_this_month);
        leftover_payment = (monthly_payment - interest_for_this_month);
        loan_balance = (loan_balance - leftover_payment);
        printf("Month = (%i),   This month's interest = (%.2lf)   leftover payment = (%.2lf)   Loan Balance = (%.2lf\n\n)"); month, interest_for_this_month, leftover_payment, loan_balance;
        
    }
    
    printf("\nTotal Interest = %.2lf\n", total_interest);
    printf("Final Loan Balance = %.2lf\n\n\n", loan_balance);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us how you're running the program and the input you're providing?

Comment: You should get in the practice of checking the return value from `scanf` to determine if a value was successfully read.

Comment: `monthly_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate/1200;` Integer division strikes again! (Tip: use "print debugging" to output intermediary results. Simple to do and you'll find the cause of problems like this for yourself.)

Comment: I'm running the program through Putty and OnlineGDB. My inputs in order of how my code prompts the user are: 200000, 30, 6, 1199.10

Comment: @Noah `...(%.2lf\n\n)"); month, in...` in the monthly print line... What's that semi-colon doing there? That's supposed to be a comma... Don't write such long lines! Break it up into several print statements!

Comment: @Fe2O3 or just break up the format string across multiple lines.

Comment: @Chris Perhaps. Beginners often fondle (and replicate) variables and values (creating confusion, then, often try to cram all the output into one output statement... This problem probably would not have arisen if the OP had started with one print statement for each term... Just my opinion... :-)

Comment: haha sorry for that long print statement, my professor wants it to be like that. I changed that semi colon to a comma. I tried making that 1200 on my monthly_interest_rate into a variable called pc and dividing that, the print debugging went well up until that point.

Comment: Forgive my economics, but isn't the whole point to pay back the loan? Are you sure you're calculating the right value?

Comment: fixed my integer division issue on my monthly_interest_rate, also removed precision on my scanf. Everything prints right so far except my monthly interest rate shows too many decimal places and my final_month doesn't print at all!

Comment: @Noah It is poor Stackoverflow etiquette to change the question once answers arrive.  Please review [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Question rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

At least thee problems:

**Integer division**

`annual_interest_rate/1200` is an `int` division with an `int` quotient (0 in this case).  Use `annual_interest_rate/1200.0` for `double` division.

**Uninitialized variable**

`total_interest` uninitialized.   Add `total_interest = 0;` [@Fe2O3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320707/intro-to-c-variables-arent-printing-properly/77320804?noredirect=1#comment136311853_77320804).

**`scanf()` does not support a *precision***

Remove `".2"` from `scanf("%.2lf"...` to avoid undefined behavior (UB).

---

**Advanced**

Real money code would use either decimal floating point or perhaps scaling by 100 (a whole number amount of *cents*) and rounding the interest calculations to get exact money answers.  Then the last interest payment needs an adjustment up/down a few cents.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `);` in the wrong place in your `printf()` line in the loop.  You have:

```
    printf("Month = (%i),   This month's interest = (%.2lf)   leftover payment = (%.2lf)   Loan Balance = (%.2lf\n\n)"); month, interest_for_this_month, leftover_payment, loan_balance;
```

Which could be reformatted as:

```
    printf("Month = (%i),   This month's interest = (%.2lf)   "
           "leftover payment = (%.2lf)   Loan Balance = (%.2lf\n\n)");
    month, interest_for_this_month, leftover_payment, loan_balance;
```

The last of those lines is a series of comma operators with no side effects; you should get a warning about that.   The first two lines are a call to `printf()` that expects 4 values but is not given any.  I've split the string using string concatenation.  Your compiler should be complaining about both the `printf()` call and the set of comma operators; if it isn't, turn up the warning options or get a better compiler.

What you need is:

```
    printf("Month = (%i),   This month's interest = (%.2lf)   "
           "leftover payment = (%.2lf)   Loan Balance = (%.2lf\n\n)",
           month, interest_for_this_month, leftover_payment, loan_balance);
```

---

There may be — there probably are — other problems, but this is why the loop is not printing anything useful.  Pay heed to other answers and comments.